# Logging Data after Subscribe in Angular Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I'm new to the `Observables` and working my way through the Angular documentation.
Here's how I `subscribe` to the service and get data.

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => this.localData = data)
```

Now, I'm struggling to log it within the component (`console.log`) for debug purposes.

I've tried:

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => this.localData = data, complete => console.log(this.localData));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `console.log` inside of the "success" callback:

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
  this.localData = data; 
  console.log(this.localData);
});
```

If you want to do it in the "complete" callback (assuming that the Observable does complete):

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
  data => { this.localData = data; },
  error => {},
  () => { console.log(this.localData); });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
     (data) =>  {
       this.localData = data, 
       console.log(this.localData)
     }
    , error => // the second one is error!),
    , complete => //complete is the third one;
```

You need to console your data inside subscribe on success or in complete. You are printing inside when the subscription returns a error